# Load sql script in PySpark notebook

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

In Azure Synapse Analytics, I want to keep my **SQL** queries **separately** from my **PySpark notebook**.

So I have created some SQL scripts. And I would like to use them in my PySpark notebook.

- Is it possible ?
- And what is the python code to load a SQL script into a variable ?

[image: Notebooks and SQL Scripts in Azure Synapse Analytics]

Comment: Just load as a text file and pass the text to the your query code. A better question would be how to load files from Azure Synapse via a notebook there. I assume you can find that answer online.

Answer (score 1):

As I undertand the ask here , is can we read the SQL scripts which we have already created from pysprk notebook . I was looking at the storage account whiched is mapped  to my synapse analytics studio ( ASA)  and i do not see that the notebook or SQL scripts are stored there . So i dont think you can convert the existing SQL script to Pyspark code within the ASA . Yes if you export the SQL scripts and then upload to storage and then read the scripts from the notebook .